# How do I change the aws security groups using BOTO3

Tags: amazon-web-services, fabric, boto3, aws-security-group

HI I am running a publicvm with a dynamic IP, and I want some security groups to point to the correct office IP everytime the IP change. I can get my office IP using https://wtfismyip.com/text. How do I take that new IP and edit the existing security groups using boto3? And I am planning to use fabric to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to edit the security group rules using Boto3. You have to delete the old rule and add a new rule. I haven't tried this one before but this what you have to do. Tweak it to your needs.

[Removes one or more ingress rules from a security group](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.revoke_security_group_ingress)

[Adds one or more ingress rules to a security group](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.authorize_security_group_ingress)

```
    conn = boto3.client('ec2')
    conn.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=my_group_id,IpProtocol="tcp",CidrIp="new_ip/32",FromPort=443,ToPort=443)
```